# How to keep the string as it is in certain block but change it in another block

Tags: python, regex, logic

I am having a file with 2 blocks slightly diffrent from each other.Below is the content of the file

```
 Other codes in the file
 function void one(int x)
     message_same
     rest of the code
  endfunction
 Other codes in the file
  function void othercheck ::two(int x)
      message_same
      rest of the code
   endfunction

   Different codes in the file
```

I read this file in a list and made some changes and would like to write into another file.

But I want if "message_same" is seen under function one then,it should be written as it is but if it is seen under function two,then it should delete the line or do not write that line into the output file. Other line of code should remain as it is

Expected Output:

```
 Other codes in the file
 virtual function void one(int x)
 message_same
 rest of the code
 endfunction
 Other codes in the file

  function void two:: othercheck(int x)
  rest of the code
  endfunction  
  Different codes in the file
```

I tried with the following code:

```
for word in words:
     found_one_function=re.search('virtual function',word)
     if found_in_function :
        found_in_end=re.search('endfunction',word)
        if not found_in_end:
            found_in_function=True

   while(found_in_function):
           fw.write(word)
           continue

   if re.search('message_same', word):
        continue

   fw.write(word)
```

I understand that logically it's not right but I am not sure how to iterate after finding the virtual function till I get the end function.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Does that file contain only those two functions or should it run in an iterative mode removing `message_same` in every second function it encounters?

Comment: It contains several such functions and two is just name of the function.Main distinguish factor between two types of function is the use of '::'

Comment: So only the functions containing `::` in their signature should be stripped off `message_same` if encountered?

Comment: @zwer Yeah that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's relatively easy to do - what you want is to iterate over your `words` list (assuming each element contains a single line from your example data) and check for the beginning of the second 'type' of functions and then strip out lines containing `message_same` until you encounter a sole `endfunction`, something like:

```
# assuming `words` list with each line of your data
# if not it's as easy as: with open("input.txt") as f: words = [line for line in f]
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:  # open output.txt for writing
    in_function = False  # an identifier to tell us we are within a `::` function
    for line in words:  # iterate over words
        if in_function:  # we are inside of a `::` function...
            if line.strip() == "endfunction":  # end of the function
                in_function = False
            elif "message_same" in line:  # skip this line
                continue
        # detect function begin if there is "function" in the line followed with ::
        elif "function" in line and line.find("function") < line.find("::"):
            in_function = True
        f.write(line)  # write the line to the output file
        # f.write("\n")  # uncomment if the lines in your `words` are not terminated
```

For a file whose lines have been loaded as elements of `words` containing:

```
 Other codes in the file
 function void one(int x)
     message_same
     rest of the code
  endfunction
 Other codes in the file
  function void othercheck ::two(int x)
      message_same
      rest of the code
   endfunction

   Different codes in the file
```

It will produce `output.txt` containing:

```
 Other codes in the file
 function void one(int x)
     message_same
     rest of the code
  endfunction
 Other codes in the file
  function void othercheck ::two(int x)
      rest of the code
   endfunction

   Different codes in the file
```

You can have as many functions as you want, and they don't need to be ordered - the processing will be applied only on those with `::`.

Comment: There are other lines also other than the functions outside of it. In trying your code,I am losing data which is not part of function.I don't want to loose other data.

Comment: @Saurabh - in that case you're not presenting your whole case. The above code will remove only lines between lines that have `function` followed by `::` and the next sole `endfunction`. You've set those constraints and the above code works with them, if there is something more to know about your data do post it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the question. I need rest part of the code to be as it is. Just if message_same is seen inside function with ::,it should not be written in output file

Comment: @Saurabh - the code above produces exactly the output you've wanted, check the updated snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each line in the file; use a flag to track whether the process is *IN* a `::` function; use the flag to discard a `message_same` line; modify line as needed; write line to the new file.

```
import re

special = re.compile(r'function.*?::')
in_special_func = False
with open(in_filepath) as in_file, open(out_filepath, 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if special.search(line):
            in_special_func = True
        if 'endfunction' in line:
            in_special_func = False
        if in_special_func and 'message_same' in line:
            #skip
            continue
        # make line modifications here if needed
        # line = modify(line)
        # line = some_variation_of(line)
        # print(line)
        out_file.write(line)
```

---

PREVIOUS ERRONEOUS ATTEMPT

Construct a regex that will capture a complete function

```
f_re = re.compile(r'function.*?endfunction', flags = re.DOTALL)
```

Construct a regex to identify the *special* functions

```
special = re.compile(r'function.*?::')
```

Construct a a regex that will match the line that needs to be removed

```
message_same = re.compile(r'^\s*message_same\s*\n', flags = re.MULTILINE)
```

Read the file into a string:

```
with open(in_filepath) as in_file:
   s = in_file.read()
```

Iterate over all the functions; if a function is special remove the line; make other modifications to the function; write it to a file.

```
with open(out_filepath, 'w') as out_file:
   for f in f_re.findall(s):
      #print(f)
      if special.search(f):
         f = message_same.sub('', f)
      # make other changes here
      # assuming the result is a single string
      out_file.write(f)
      #print(f)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it's still showing message_same in function with '::'. Function without '::' is working as expected.Also there are lines outside of these function also,I want to write those lines also to the output file

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to remove the 'message same' line for every function with a signature that contains 'function' and 'two'. This assumes that the structure of your input file is very consistent.

```
# read file into list of lists (each inner list is a block)
with open('code_blocks.txt', 'r') as f:
    blocks = [block.split('\n') for block in f.read().split('\n\n')]

# iterate over blocks
for block in blocks:
    # if first line contains 'function' and 'two' and second line contains 'message same'
    if 'function' in block[0] and '::' in block[0] and 'message_same' in block[1]:
        # remove message same
        block.pop(block.index(block[1]))

# combine list of lists back into single string and write it out
with open('code_blocks_out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n\n'.join(['\n'.join(block) for block in blocks]))
```

Comment: Hi,I actually have Words=[ ] as my list which already have everything but I need to strip the line 'same_message' in functions with '::' and keep the message in function that starts with virtual function.

Comment: I updated the code to handle function with '::' in the function signature rather than the word 'two'. Based on what you've described, you just have one requirement: remove 'message_same' from any function with '::'. In all other cases, do nothing. I believe my answer accomplishes this. Is there something else it needs to do?